# Why does export-csv not run properly in Powershell on SQL Server?

Tags: powershell, csv

I am no expert with Powershell; however, I am trying to simply run an Invoke-Sqlcmd and save the results as a .csv file. I am looping through multiple *.sql files as the queries. When I run the following Powershell from a Windows10 desktop, everything runs fine but when I run this from our SQL Server, I am receiving errors on the export-csv command.

Here is my Powershell:

```
#Prompt for date
$DatePrompt = Read-Host -Prompt 'Enter the database date. (YYYY-MM-DD)'
#Convert to date
$DatabaseDate = [DateTime]::Parse($DatePrompt)
#Create FileDate string
$FileDate = $DatabaseDate.ToString("yyyyMMdd")
#Create SQLDate string
$SQLDate = $DatabaseDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")
#--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
#Provide SQLServerName
$SQLServer ="SQLSERVER\MISDATA"
#Provide Database Name
$DatabaseName ="StagingDB"
#Set MonthStart and MonthEnd (YYYY-MM-DD)
$Variables = "FileDate = $SQLDate"
#Scripts Folder Path
$FolderPath ="\\SQLSERVER\MISDATA\Queries"
#Output Folder Path
$OutputFolderPath ="\\SQLSERVER\MISDATA\Results"
#--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
#Loop through the .sql files and run them
foreach ($filename in get-childitem -path $FolderPath -filter "*.sql")
{   #Run SQL Query
    Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance $SQLServer -Database $DatabaseName -InputFile $filename.fullname -Variable $Variables -Querytimeout 0|
    #Export to CSV
    Export-Csv -NoTypeInformation -Path ($OutputFolderPath + "\" + $FileDate + "-" + $filename.basename + ".csv") -Encoding UTF8
    #Write to ConsoleHost
    Write-Host $filename.name "completed"
}
```

Here is the error:

```
Export-Csv : Cannot open file because the current provider (Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.PSProvider\SqlServer) cannot open a file.
At C:\MISDATA\Queries\Run Scripts.ps1:26 char:5
+     Export-Csv -NoTypeInformation -Path ($OutputFolderPath + "\" + $FileDate + " ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Export-Csv], PSInvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ReadWriteFileNotFileSystemProvider,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ExportCsvCommand
sqlquery1.sql completed
Export-Csv : Cannot open file because the current provider (Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.PSProvider\SqlServer) cannot open a file.
At C:\MISDATA\Queries\Run Scripts.ps1:26 char:5
+     Export-Csv -NoTypeInformation -Path ($OutputFolderPath + "\" + $FileDate + " ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Export-Csv], PSInvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ReadWriteFileNotFileSystemProvider,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ExportCsvCommand
sqlquery2.sql completed
Export-Csv : Cannot open file because the current provider (Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.PSProvider\SqlServer) cannot open a file.
At C:\MISDATA\Queries\Run Scripts.ps1:26 char:5
+     Export-Csv -NoTypeInformation -Path ($OutputFolderPath + "\" + $FileDate + " ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Export-Csv], PSInvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ReadWriteFileNotFileSystemProvider,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ExportCsvCommand
sqlquery3.sql completed
```

Comment: Maybe your commands are changing your current working location to a non-filesystem provider. What happens if you `cd c:` before your `Export-Csv` ?

Comment: You may need to wrap the `Get-ChildItem ...` part in brackets inside the `foreach($filename in ...`

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify powershell ruled UNC format.
`$OutputFolderPath ="Filesystem::\\SQLSERVER\MISDATA\Results"`
or
`$OutputFolderPath ="Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\FileSystem::\\SQLSERVER\MISDATA\Results"`

Comment: I know you're excited, but please try to keep your language under control. Think of Stack Overflow as more like Wikipedia than like Reddit.